# Gromov hyperbolic metric spaces are quasi-convex

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, hyperbolic-geometry, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

I'm aware about the fact stated above, but I'm not able to find some references or proofs besides Gromov's *Hyperbolic Groups - Essays in Group Theory*. I'll state things precisely. I will consider a complete geodesic metric space $(X,d)$. Given $x,y\in X$, we denote any short geodesic joinning $x$ and $y$ by $[x,y]$.

**Definition:** a complete geodesic metric space $(X,d)$ is said to be *Gromov $\delta$-hyperbolic* if every geodesic triangle whose vertices are $x_1,x_2,x_3$ satisfy the following condition: the distance between any $x\in [x_i,x_j]$ and $[x_i,x_j]\cup[x_j,x_k]$ is less than $\delta$, where we take index $i,j,k$ mod.3

**Definition:** A complete geodesic metric space $(X,d)$ is *(A,B)-quasi-convex* if any two geodesic segments $\alpha,\beta:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ satisfy the following condition:
$$d^H(\alpha([0,1]),\beta([0,1]))\leqslant A\max\{d(\alpha(0),\beta(0)),d(\alpha(1),\beta(1))\}+B$$
where $d^H$ is the Hausdorff distance.

**Theorem:** If $(X,d)$ is a complete geodesic metric space and is $\delta$-hyperbolic, then $(X,d)$ is $(A,B)$-quasi convex for some $A,B$.

Does anyone know some reference for the proof? It seems to be a well-known fact on the context. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Brigson and Haefliger discuss quasiconvexity in their book *Metric spaces of nonpositive curvature* (pp 460-464), but only in the context of hyperbolic groups. Their definition of quasiconvexity is similar to what you have, but it only has the upper bound.

Comment: Thanks again for helping. That is what was missing for me to change the statement of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upper bound, though I have not seen it written in precisely this form, is a quick consequence of the thinness of triangles. Here is  something from *A Course in Metric Geometry* by Burago, Burago, Ivanov:

> **Lemma 8.4.2** A shortest path $[ab]$ belongs to the $(d(b,c)+\delta)$-neighborhood of a shortest path $[ac]$.

The authors omit the proof, which is easy: $[ab]$ is in the $\delta$-neighborhood of $[ac]\cup [bc]$, and the latter set is in the $d(b,c)$-neighborhood of $[ac]$.

Applying the above lemma twice (moving endpoints of geodesic one at a time), you'll get 
$$d^H(\alpha([0,1]),\beta([0,1])) \leqslant d(\alpha(0),\beta(0)) +  d(\alpha(1),\beta(1)) +2\delta$$
which gives the right hand side with $A=2$, $B=2\delta$.

---

The left hand side cannot hold as stated: what if $\alpha,\beta$ are the same long geodesic path traveled in different directions?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not figuring out what you mean by "moving endpoints of geodesics one at a time". Could you, if it doesn't bother you, perhaps fill out a little bit more details? Thank you very much again.

Comment: @matgaio Say, your geodesics are $[ab]$ and $[cd]$. Then you first estimate the Hausdorff distance from $[ab]$ to $[ad]$, and then the distance from $[ad]$ to $[cd]$. Then use the triangle inequality.

Comment: Ok! Now I've figured out! Thank you again!

Comment: @matgaio But what about the lower bound? Do you have a form of it that works, perhaps as stated in Gromov's paper?

Comment: Actually, I don't know about the lower bound. In fact, all I was concerned about was the upper bound (I have to prove some sort of continuity here using the upper bound). I just put the entire statement the way I've read in a lecture note I have here. Reading after, I realized I do not need the upper bound. Perhaps it is not precise. I didn't thik much about the lower bound yet. I will try to understand. Perhaps I should change the way the question was proposed, so the answer corresponds to the question. What do you think?

Comment: @matgaio Sure, if you bring the question to the form that better matches the answer, the whole thing will make more sense to those reading it in the future.